# SharePoint 2013: Calendar control click takes to top of the page

Tags: 2013, calendar, browser-compatibility, chrome

I am using date time field (Calendar control) in SharePoint 2013 page layout, the calendar control is half way down to the page. Once calendar control is clicked, it takes to the top of the page instead of positioning the right control in chrome browser. Its working fine in IE and Firefox.

Is this default behavior of Chrome or is this resolvable issue?

Same issue reported on Technet with no answers:
[Calendar Control scroll position issue in Chrome](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7de0f717-0bd2-470a-8b79-8d7837eb4761/calendar-control-scroll-position-issue-in-chrome?forum=sharepointgeneral)